# confusing conditional formating

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

My Managers have asked me to create a worksheet were the activities of certain teams will be shown only for the  next two weeks.

to build this table[image] I used the formula =FILTER(Table1[Key message],Table1[Date]=Table2[@[ Start Date]]," nothing scheduled")the text

Now I am trying to make conditionally format the colour activities according to the team who his responsible for them

I am trying to use this formula for it to work

=IF(AND(Grid!E4:E50='Bi-Weekly Analisys'!A34,Grid!F4:F50='Bi-Weekly Analisys'!A3:N25),TRUE,FALSE)

Basically the idea in my head is to conditional say if the team is this and if you can find the activity in the  2 week table  colour it with the team  colour.

[image]

It would be added bonus if I could use the data validation filter to make the colouring appear? (However I don't even know if that is possible...)

[image]

Any Ideas?

These are all on different sheets.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.

Comment: " I want to evaluate if I want to change the color of the text " .. If you want to change? So what is the target colour.?  for which case (value)?  (it was not mentioned.) | The 2nd paragraph seems to be in just 1 sentence.. maybe it is to intense to the audience to understand.. would you mind expanding it ? (into multiple simple sentence/point form..  or share an example maybe. Sharing  your research effort will be a plus )